# How do I access all routes, when an App and an included AppEngine gem define controllers with the same name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, rails-engines

I have an engine (developed by me / the company I work for) that we use on several different projects.  I just converted it  to work with rails 3.1 w/ assets pipeline and everything seems to be working... for the most part.

My problem is that I need to extend the functionality of the `UsersController` with a little bit of app-specific spice, but I'm not sure about the best way to do it.  The engine doesn't define a `Users#show` action, but this app does need it, so I added to the routes file:

```
JobEngine::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => 'home#index'

  resource :users, :only => [:show]
  resources :jobs, :only => [:show]
end
```

Then in my application I created the UsersController:

```
class UsersController < MyEngine::UsersController
  def show
  end
end
```

Then I made a `users/show.html.haml` view, I've stripped it down to only show one of the problem lines:

```
= link_to "Somewhere", job_path(3)
```

This gives me an error that reads `undefined method 'job_path' for #<#<Class:0x00000102d69900>:0x00000102d4ed30>`

Which is bizarre because *before* I made my app's `UsersController` inherit from `MyEngine::UsersController` it worked just fine.

When I do `rake routes` in the console, there are these lines:

```
users GET   /users(.:format)    {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}
job GET     /jobs/:id(.:format) {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs"}
```

I can alter the class definition to be:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
```

and then the link works just fine.  However, the engine's controller `MyEngine::UsersController` already inherits from `ApplicationController`.  I can put code into my app's `ApplicationController` (like a `before_filter`) and it will run as expected, so I know my class definition does ultimately hit my app's `ApplicationController`, why is the job_path helper not working?

When I change the show action to read:

```
def show
  job_path(3)
end
```

I get the error:

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"jobs", :id=>3}):
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:9:in `show'
```

Which further confuses me because now it actually does recognize job_path as a method, but somehow the router isn't picking up where to go with all the correct parameters.

What am I doing wrong?  What is the correct way to extend engine controller functionality?  I saw [the extending engine functionality question here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964050/rails-engines-extending-functionality)

And followed that code example, changing my class definition to instead re-open `MyEngine::UsersController` but I still get the exact same results concerning `job_path(NUMBER)`

UPDATE:

Ok I sort of figured out what's going on.  Let's say your engine has a job_path route, and your application has a job_path route.  If you're on a page that was accessed via an engine's controller, you can call the engine's helper with just `job_path`, but you can also call the main application's helper with `main_app.job_path`.

Likewise, if you're on a page accessed via one of your application's controllers, you access the engine's helper with `my_engine.job_path` and your own application's helper with `job_path`.  This is assuming that you have something like `mount MyEngine::Engine => "/my_engine", :as => 'my_engine'`.

When you inherit an engine controller from your application, it then completely changes your route helpers to think you're in the context of the engine through the controller/view lifecycle.  So to fix my problem all I really have to do is change it to be `main_app.job_path(3)` and it works.

I'm not completely satisfied with this solution because it feels a little...weird.  Maybe I have a partial on this page that will be used on a separate non-inheriting page.  Now the link helper will only work for one of the two pages, but never both =\  Am I missing something here...?

Comment: You make a good point in the last paragraph.  I'm also looking for a way to dynamically determine in a helper (in my case, not being used by a view but as a before_filter, so not technically a helper but a module included in both my App Controller and my Engine Controller) whether to use `main_app.some_path` or just `some_path`, depending on what class is including it.  Any solutions?

Comment: It appears that you can just use main_app from everywhere.  I guess just like your engine defines main_app as the RouteSet of the application, the application defines main_app as the RouteSet of itself.  This fits with the idea that ["A Rails application is actually just a 'supercharged' engine"](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html#what-are-engines-questionmark).  Still, I don't like it.  What happens when the named routes are being used in a gem dependency and it's too late to preface them with main_app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though you can make this approach work, the semantics do not create a clean architecture.  You can surmise this from the duplication of the `Users` controller - which implies that some `User` functionality is handled in the AppEngine, and some is handled in the parent app itself.

Instead, think about what functionality exists uniquely within the app, and which is packaged into the AppEngine gem.  Perhaps with *JobEngine*, as you call it, your `Users` controller there is actually a `UsersStatisticsController` and, in the app, the controller there is the 'true generic' `UsersController` that handles CRUD, profiles, message queue, etc.

If you feel you must unify them into a single controller (rather than giving them distinct nomenclature), then you are best to create a **Namespaced** controller, where the various functionality can be conjoined thereby.

Even though this adds complexity, it's generally arguable that this is the most sound solution.  [Here's another post on SO about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456962/railsengine-namespacing-controller-and-models)

Comment: While not the answer I was originally looking for, it's probably the best direction to go.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your Mount path in main app's routes with below,

```
mount MyEngine::Engine => "/"
```

This would solve your problem.