# Rails Engines--how to bypass main_app for named routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines

In [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000536/how-do-i-access-all-routes-when-an-app-and-an-included-appengine-gem-define-con), the end of the question begins to address this issue, but it wasn't the main question, which was answered there already.

I have a module that's included both in `ApplicationController` and in `MyEngineController`.  Suppose some of the module's instance methods use `login_url` or some other named route.  It works from ApplicationController but not from `MyEngineController`.  I could replace that with `main_app.login_url`, which will make it work for both, but that seems very verbose, and anyway, what if the code is already part of a gem dependency?  How do I make it work post-facto from the engine I'm coding?

When I try using any named helper, here's what I get:

```
ActionController::RoutingError: 
    No route matches {:action=>"new", :controller=>"sessions"}
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:532:in `raise_routing_error'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:528:in `rescue in generate'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:520:in `generate'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:561:in `generate'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:586:in `url_for'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/url_for.rb:148:in `url_for'
actionpack-3.2.8/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:213:in `login_url'
```

Note that `:controller=>"sessions"` would have to be `:controller=>"/sessions"` (with the slash to put it at root namespace), but that's not an option I can pass to named routes AFAIK.  I tried adding this code:

```
extend ActiveSupport::Concern
included do
  main_app.install_helpers(self)
end
```

in MyEngineController, but it didn't help.  (`install_helpers` is very poorly documented.  Can anyone explain what it's supposed to do?)

Answer (score 2):

For now, I'm going with this solution (in MyEngineController):

```
protected
def url_for options=nil
  begin
    super options
  rescue ActionController::RoutingError
    main_app.url_for options
  end
end
```

I'm not such a fan of it because, in general, [exceptions shouldn't be used for flow control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546514/java-exceptions-as-control-flow).  So what other suggestions do you have?